# How to control SwiftUI app from AppDelegate?

Tags: swift, swiftui, appdelegate

I'd like pressing a notification to open up a certain page in the SwiftUI app.
I'm able to trigger the print statement "notification was tapped" when the notification is tapped by having this code in the AppDelegate.swift

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
      func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
      }

      func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            print("notification was tapped")
            // add code to open specific swiftUI view here!
            completionHandler()
      }
}
```

How can control the view that will be opened from the AppDelegate.swift?

Comment: It can be done like in solutions provided in [App Delegate Accessing Environment Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379898/app-delegate-accessing-environment-object)